# Moving views to a separate file without violating PEP-8

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pep8

I am making a Flask web app, and, as usual, my `__init__.py` goes something like this:

```
import a
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from . import views
```

Recently I've learned that not having top level import violates PEP-8, so this code is bad. But my `views.py` looks like that:

```
from . import app
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    pass
```

So it requires `app` to be instantiated before `views.py` is imported. How should I go about changing it so it would be compliant with PEP-8 but still work?

Comment: Have you considered writing a function to create the views, that takes the `app` as an argument? `from views import create_views; create_views(app)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not "violating PEP 8".

The PEP 8 document - the guidelines for coding style has a session titled:
"[A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id15)", where in the role of the document is reiterated as a **guideline** for *style*.

Now, changing the import statement order for the application to work is part of the fundamental logic of the application - the order of these statements makes a diference, and it is not a matter of style. So much for "style" them.

Now, people worried about "violating PEP 8" usually are so not due to how the source code looks for humans, but rather because there is some linter program running on the commit/test/build workflow that spills errors on so called "PEP 8 violations".  Non of these linters has (as of yet) the commons sense required by the true spirit of "coding style guidelines" of PEP 8.

So, just mark the lines with the late imports in a way the linter program does not complain. Usually that is accomplished by adding an inline comment to the end of the line reading `# noQA` - and you can do it - but the exact textt may vary depending on your linter program.